# Excel Macro - Using find in a Do Loop

Tags: vba, excel

Within a Do Loop that I have, I want to use the 'find' function, but it seems to keep bumping me out of the loop after one iteration when I try this.

FYI, I'm not great at VB, better with web code eg: PHP etc

If I comment out the row that begins sfFamilyCol = wsSFDC.Rows(1)...... then the loop will run as many times as it should.  With that row in there, it doesnt throw an error but it only goes through once.

I'm wondering if there is some special way of handling .Find within a loop?  Or something else I have no idea about?  Any help appreciated...

```
Option Explicit

Sub mapTags()

Dim wsMP As Worksheet: Set wsMP = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MP")
Dim wsSFDC As Worksheet: Set wsSFDC = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SFDC")
Dim wsMap As Worksheet: Set wsMap = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping")
Dim wsUp As Worksheet: Set wsUp = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Upload")
Dim wsCol As Worksheet: Set wsCol = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MP_Columns")
Dim wsFmt As Worksheet: Set wsFmt = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tag Name Formats")

Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim SFDCrow As Long, SFDCID As String, sfCol As Long
Dim MPID As String, mpTagGroup As String, mpTagName As String, mpTagCol As Long, mapTagName As String
Dim sfTagFamily As String, sfTagGroup As String, sfTagName As String, sfFamilyCol As Long, sfGroupCol As Long
Dim oRange As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

''Get Contact Record
For i = 2 To 2 Step -1  'Change i to 25000 later...

MPID = wsMP.Cells(i, 1).Value
sfCol = wsSFDC.Columns(2).Find(What:=MPID, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row
'MsgBox sfCol

''Go Through each MP Contact Tag Colum
For k = 10 To 1 Step -1
    mpTagGroup = wsCol.Cells(k, 1).Value
    If Not mpTagGroup = "" Then
        mpTagCol = wsMP.Rows(1).Find(What:=mpTagGroup, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column

        '' Get the Tag Name
        mpTagName = wsMP.Cells(i, mpTagCol).Value
        If Not mpTagName = "" Then

            ''Get the Mapped SFDC Tags
            Set oRange = wsMap.Columns(1)
            Set aCell = oRange.Find(What:=mpTagGroup, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            'MsgBox mapTagGroup

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                Set bCell = aCell
                'FoundAt = aCell.Row
                Do
                    Set aCell = oRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

                    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                        If aCell.Row = bCell.Row Then Exit Do
                        'FoundAt = FoundAt & ", " & aCell.Row
                        mapTagName = wsMap.Cells(aCell.Row, 2).Value
                        If mapTagName = mpTagName Then
                            sfTagFamily = wsMap.Cells(aCell.Row, 4).Value
                            sfTagGroup = wsMap.Cells(aCell.Row, 5).Value
                            sfTagName = wsMap.Cells(aCell.Row, 6).Value

                            'MsgBox aCell & " " & mapTagName & ": " & sfTagFamily & " " & sfTagGroup & " " & sfTagName
                            MsgBox sfTagFamily

                            ''Set the SDDC TAG FAMILY to TRUE
                            sfFamilyCol = wsSFDC.Rows(1).Find(What:=sfTagGroup, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
                            MsgBox sfFamilyCol

                        End If
                    Else
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop
            End If

            'MsgBox "The Search String has been found in these rows: " & FoundAt


        End If
    End If
Next k
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a [good article](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/FindAll.aspx) so start here. I think you just need to clean up the sequence of using the *Find Method*. Also, try isolating which part doesn't work by adding break points so we can focus on that line instead.

Comment: Another [link](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) for your reading pleasure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is only one `.Find` operation remembered and any subsequent `.FindNext` will use the parameters of the last `.Find`. Your `Set aCell = oRange.FindNext(...` is using the `sfFamilyCol = wsSFDC.Rows(1).Find(...` during the second iteration.

That `sfFamilyCol = wsSFDC.Rows(1).Find(...` is using `lookat:=xlPart` but perhaps you can change it to something like,

```
if application.countif(wsSFDC.Rows(1), chr(42) & sfTagGroup & chr(42)) then _
    sfFamilyCol = application.match(chr(42) & sfTagGroup & chr(42), wsSFDC.Rows(1), 0)
```

That should be sufficient error control to only attempt a wildcard `Match` if it looks like it can be found. Subsequent calls to `Set aCell = oRange.FindNext(...` should remain unaffected.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didnt realise the .FindNext would use the new .Find.

Using .Match instead of .Find works well